# .htaccess rewrite subdirectory to a different subdirectory on a different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to configure a redirect for the domain kb3mmy.net.  I'd like it to work that if somebody goes to [kb3mmy.net/blog](http://kb3mmy.net/blog) it redirects them to [christiaanconover.com/category/kb3mmy/](http://christiaanconover.com/category/kb3mmy/).  This is the only redirect I want to take place like this, so I can hard code the subdirectories.

Also, there's an existing redirect rule set up on kb3mmy.net that sends any traffic to the root of that domain to a sub page on christiaanconover.com, but any sub page traffic to kb3mmy.net to the corresponding sub page on christiaanconover.com, so that rule cannot be affected by the new one.  Here's the code for the existing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://christiaanconover.com/kb3mmy/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://christiaanconover.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$  http://christiaanconover.com/category/kb3mmy/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://christiaanconover.com/kb3mmy/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://christiaanconover.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be doing the trick, it still redirects me using the existing rewrite rules I've had in place.

Comment: @Christiaan you're previous redirects are 301, so browsers cache them! clear chache and test again!

Comment: I cleared all cache data, and it's still redirecting using the old rules.

Comment: @Christiaan what do you type in location and where do you redirect to?

Comment: I type in http://kb3mmy.net/blog and get redirected to http://christiaanconover.com/blog, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I'll check it out.  The existing rules work perfectly so I'd rather not mess with them, I just want to add one that's a subset of those.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} kb3mmy.net
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$  http://christiaanconover.com/category/kb3mmy/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} kb3mmy.net
RewriteRule ^$ http://christiaanconover.com/kb3mmy/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} kb3mmy.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://christiaanconover.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```